# .NET Jquery Script Error

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

Trying to do a Jquery function, everything seems to be setup fine, but I get this error in my browser console log

> SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is not defined
>   bootstrap.js (20,1)
>
> HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
>   1 (1,1)
>   2 CSS3121: The media query -ms-viewport has been deprecated.
>
> SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is not defined
>   bootstrap.js (21,1)
>
> SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined
>   SendEmail.js (1,1)

This is my View Scripts/Styles:

```
@model Linkofy.Models.EmailAccount

@{
ViewBag.Title = "SendMail";
}
@section Styles {
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/Edit.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
@section Scripts {
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Javascript/SendEmail.js")"></script>      
}
```

My Function (SendEmail.js):

```
$("#templateName").on("change", function () {

var tempID = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
var url = "/Identifiers/TemplateData/" + tempID;
console.log()

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: url, // Variabel
    showLoader: true,
    success: test // Function
});

});
function test(data) {
data = $.parseJSON(data);
$('#subject').val(data.subject);
$('#body').val(data.body);
}
```

Bundles:

```
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
}
```

Can't post without padding out the text on this file, so here is my whole layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - linkofy</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar" style="background-color: LightSteelBlue;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Linkofy", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Domains", "Index", "Identifiers")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Clients", "Index", "Clients")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Links", "Index", "Links")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Status", "Index", "Status")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Orb Online - Liam Cook</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show your layout.cshtml?

Comment: @DanielA.White added it :)

Comment: Show your browser console.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers do you mean from the fn+f12 window? ive put everything at the top there, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Lucie - Yes, fn + f12 and show me console

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers I have added it at the bottom as a photo :)

Comment: I know what is your problem in your solution. You have referenced all jquery and bootstrap  library  twice...  :)  First place it is in your Bundles, Second place is in your header tag or in body, footer tags. Right???  Result is: you are getting  with conflict two  jQuery and  bootstrap  libraries. My solutions is that:  Try to declare all  script  libraries in one  place. For example, only in  header tag. If you are using boundling try to reference it with rendering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error can only be caused by one of three things:

1. Your JavaScript file is not being properly loaded into your page
2. You have a botched version of jQuery. This could happen because
   someone edited the core file, or a plugin may have overwritten the $
       variable.
3. You have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded, and as
   such, before jQuery is fully loaded.

You should check the Firebug net panel to see if the file is actually being loaded properly. If not, it will be highlighted red and will say "404" beside it. If the file is loading properly, that means that the issue is number 2.

Make sure all jQuery javascript code is being run inside a code block such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
});
```

This will ensure that your code is being loaded after jQuery has been initialized.

One final thing to check is to make sure that you are not loading any plugins before you load jQuery. Plugins extend the "$" object, so if you load a plugin before loading jQuery core, then you'll get the error you described.

**Note:** If you're loading code which does not require jQuery to run it does not need to be placed inside the jQuery ready handler. That code may be separated using

> document.readyState

Make sure that in your layout in header tags scripts should be like this order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```